# Find the area under a Gaussian

Tags: gaussian-integral

I have a Gaussian function defined by: $h_{\alpha}(x)=\exp(-\alpha x^2)$

How do I find the area under the graph for an arbitrary value of $\alpha$

My working:

$\displaystyle∫_{−∞}^\infty \exp⁡(−^2 )\ =\sqrt{}$

$\displaystyle∫_{−∞}^\infty \exp⁡(−a^2 )\ =\sqrt{a}\ ??$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} dx$$
Let $x\sqrt{a}=t \implies dx=\frac{dt}{\sqrt{a}}$, then
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{a}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}} .$$